# How to fetch the records from cursor which contains columns from different table?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

**FIRST PROCEDURE**

create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE
(
P_LAF_PK IN NUMBER,
P_RET_VAL   OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_RET_VAL FOR

SELECT LAF.AF_FEE,LAF.AF_FEES_PAYABLE,
LAH.LH_DECISION_DT,LAH.LH_ISSUED
FROM LH_APP_HDR LAH JOIN LIQ_APP_FEE LAF
ON AF_PK = LH_PK
WHERE LAF_APPID = P_LAF_PK;

END TESTPROCEDURE;

Calling this procedure in another procedure

**SECOND PROCEDURE**

create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE1
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
V_LIQ_CURSOR       SYS_REFCURSOR;
V_LIQ_CURSOR_OUT1  LIQ_APP_FEE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

TESTPROCEDURE (2727,V_LIQ_CURSOR);

LOOP

FETCH V_LIQ_CURSOR INTO V_LIQ_CURSOR_OUT1;  -- **getting error in this line like "Return
types of Result Set variables or query do not match"**

EXIT WHEN V_LIQ_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

IF(V_LIQ_CURSOR_OUT1.AF_FEE != 0) THEN

SELECT (V_LIQ_CURSOR_OUT1.AF_FEES_PAYABLE + V_LIQ_CURSOR_OUT1.AF_FEE) INTO V_TOTALFEE FROM DUAL;

END IF;

END  TESTPROCEDURE1;

**Can anyone tell me how to get the result from cursor which  contains multiple table columns.**

**NOTE:**

I want only two columns from the first procedure